# Pass data from a controller to the $uibModal controller angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jakarta-ee

I have a page HTML that has a button "alta", when I click that button it shows an other template as a popup and in this popup, I need values of the first page fields.

here is the function of the button "alta" in the first controller:

```
        function altaFiltro(){          
        //pop up
        alert(vm.filtros.codigo);
        $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl : 'app/entities/peticion/altaFiltro.html',
            size : 'md', // sm, md, lg
            controller: "FiltrosCtrl",
            controllerAs : 'fil',resolve: {
                filtrosVm : function() { 
                     return vm.filtros.codigo
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

in the controller "FiltrosCtrl" of my template model i have:

```
    angular.module('mecenzApp').controller('FiltrosCtrl', FiltrosCtrl);

FiltrosCtrl.$inject = [ '$scope','$uibModalInstance','Filtros'];

function FiltrosCtrl($scope, $uibModalInstance,Filtros, filtrosVm) {

    var fil = this;
    fil.cancelar = cancelar;
    function cancelar() {   
        $uibModalInstance.close();
          };

    fil.guardar = guardar;
    function guardar(){
        alert(filtrosVm);
        if(fil.filtros.nombre!=null){
            Filtros.update(fil.filtros);
            $uibModalInstance.close();
        }           
    }
}
```

so I want to get the `vm.filtros.codigo` value but it gives me an error saying that it's not defined and this is normal because it is not defined in this sub-controller (if I can call it like that)

Comment: Just to clarify, you have vm.filtros.codigo available in your first code snippet but it is not defined/accessible in the second code snipped (for the modal's controller). Am I right?

Comment: vm.filtros.codigo is not defined for the other controller FiltrosCtrl which is the model controller

Comment: Looking at your updated code & replies provided, Manuel's response is what I'd go with. If you implement it correctly in your code, it should work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `resolve` property to solve this.

```
        $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl : 'app/entities/peticion/altaFiltro.html',
            size : 'md', // sm, md, lg
            controller: "FiltrosCtrl",
            controllerAs : 'fil',
            resolve: {
                filtrosVm : function() { 
                     return vm.filtros.codigo
                }
            }

        });
```

Then  `filtrosVm` will appear as a dependency for your Modals's controller.

```
function FiltrosCtrl($scope, $uibModalInstance,Filtros, filtrosVm) {

    var fil = this;
    fil.cancelar = cancelar;
    function cancelar() {   
        $uibModalInstance.close();
          };

    fil.guardar = guardar;
    function guardar(){
        alert(filtrosVm);
        if(fil.filtros.nombre!=null){
            Filtros.update(fil.filtros);
            $uibModalInstance.close();
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: i like that solution but there is something messing on it :( it gives me an error : angular.js:13920 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: 225Provider <- 225

Comment: there was an error in my answer, please check again

Comment: the alert alert(filtrosVm); gives me "undefined"

Comment: where do you have the vm.filtros.codigo ?

Comment: in the form of my first page where there is the botton "alta": <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codPeticion"
     placeholder="Escribir c&oacute;digo ..." id="field_codPeticion"
     ng-model="vm.filtros.codigo" ng-maxlength="20" />

Comment: anyway the alert alert(vm.filtros.codigo); gives me the value of the ng-model of the feild

Comment: and by the way i have other feilds to return i have jus posted one here as an exemple

Comment: please create a plunkr so we can help you out

Comment: You have an error in the resolve, updated that based on my answer.

Comment: check mine and yours and you will notice the difference

Comment: seriously i just can't see where is the error i just copied yours in mine see my code edited above

Comment: You have the same difference between your question code and your plunkr. (Your question code is correct)

Comment: guys anyone plz can tell me where exactly did I mess cause i feel like i'm getting blind

Comment: check this, it might be helpful to understand \what I am trying to say https://plnkr.co/edit/Maf7I2mdT3KXoxph77Hl?p=preview

Comment: yes i saw it and i did something like that but still does  not work

Answer (score 2):

You pass items to the modal instance by using resolve:

Much like this:

```
  resolve: {
    Filtros: function () {
      return $scope.Filtros;
    }
  }
```

Here is a [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/tRmIjfVSHZNKB5JxzO1Q?p=preview) that does that

Comment: No problem. Keep asking questions

Comment: how to use Filtros to get my item plz take a look in my code

Comment: Did you see my solution? If you saw and still did not understand then could you please create a plunk for me or paste your code here using the code editor.

Comment: Pardon me but that has to be the worst Plunk ever !! Make some effort and please get it to fail at the point it fails in your code.

Comment: the worst because i didn't ever know what is a Plunk hahah and how to use it

Answer (score 1):

finaly it works now i get 2 fields values here is the code:

parent controller:

```
vm.altaFiltro = altaFiltro;
    function altaFiltro(){          
        //pop up
        alert(vm.filtros.codigo+"/iniciativa="+vm.filtros.nombreinic);
        $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl : 'app/entities/peticion/altaFiltro.html',
            size : 'md', // sm, md, lg
            controller: "FiltrosCtrl",
            controllerAs : 'vm',
            resolve : {
                codigo : function() {
                            return vm.filtros.codigo;
                        } ,
                iniciativa : function() {
                            return vm.filtros.nombreinic;
                        } ,
            }

        });
    }
```

model controller:

```
FiltrosCtrl.$inject = [ '$scope','$uibModalInstance','Filtros','codigo','iniciativa'];

function FiltrosCtrl($scope, $uibModalInstance, Filtros,codigo,iniciativa) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.cancelar = cancelar;
    function cancelar() {   
        $uibModalInstance.close();
          };

    vm.guardar = guardar;
    function guardar(){
        alert("GUARDAR:"+codigo+"/iniciativa="+iniciativa);
        vm.filtros.codigo = codigo;
        vm.filtros.nombreinic = iniciativa;
        if(vm.filtros.nombre!=null){
            Filtros.update(vm.filtros);
            $uibModalInstance.close();
        }           
    }
}
```

Thank you so much guys !